# ¿Como evitar llenar la pila de llamadas al sistema en un método recursivo?

Tags: java, recursión, pilas, overflow

```
public static double babiloniaMethodRecursive (int number, double i) {
        if (((number / i) - (i)) <= PRECISION) {
            return (number + (i * i)) / (2 * i);
        }
        else {
            return babiloniaMethodRecursive(number, i+PRECISION);
        }
    }
```

He hecho ese método para obtener la raíz cuadrada de un número con el algoritmo de Babilonia al ser recursivo y con una precisión de 0.000001 agota la pila y produce un stackOverflow... ¿Soluciones o alternativas para evitar dicha excepción?

GRACIAS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que la condición del `if` nunca se cumple, creando una `recursividad infinita`, la cual ocasiona el `stackOverflow`; Además, la forma en que realizas los calculos no es la mas correcta, e incluso es mas difícil de entender.

Lo mas importante al momento de trabajar con `métodos recursivos` es tener claro la `condicion` que termina la `recursividad`, para evitar llamadas `infinitas`.

Restructure tu método de la siguiente forma:

```
    public static double babiloniaMethodRecursive (int number, double x, double y) {
        double precision = 0.000001; 
        
        if ( x - y <= precision) {
            return x;
        }
        else {
            x = ( x + y) / 2;
            y = number / x;
            return babiloniaMethodRecursive(number, x, y);
        }
    }
```

Por ejemplo, para sacar la raíz cuadrada de `80`:

```
System.out.println(babiloniaMethodRecursive(80,80,1));
//  La salida es 8.94427191000505
```

`number` es el número que quieres calcular la raíz, `X` inicialmente  toma el valor del numero que quieres la raíz, `y` siempre se manda 1.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!